# Pop up edit in ng grid doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I am doing similar coding as shown in this link below
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/2GZ7L/10/)

But , when I click edit button , it not hitting and not showing the modal pop up. `OnContactEdit` doesn't hit

```
$scope.OnContactEdit = function(value){

    $scope.id = value.id;
    $scope.name = value.name;
    $scope.editT = true;

};
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-click="grid.appScope.onContactEdit(row)"` in your template to access that function.  You didn't supply the code for your grid so I am working blind here.